# Cycle through object has_many association and remove certain one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im creating an object (recipe_change) that has many ingredient_changes.  However I want to run my own validation of sort and prevent the creation of ingredient_changes if they dont pass.  I started with a validation in the ingredient_changes but with that if I added an error the valid? would prevent the change from being submitted if one of the many ingredient_changes wasnt valid...which I dont want.  So then I tried the following in my create method in the recipe_change controller and this almost did the job except once it deleted one it would break the loop and not do the rest:

```
@recipe_change.ingredient_changes.each do |change|
      if ...long conditional statement...
        @recipe_change.ingredient_changes.delete(change)
      end
end
```

Is there a function like the array .reject! that works for associations like this.  At this point in the code they are not saved to the database and Im trying to not save them to the database if they dont meet my condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reject_if` to filter out invalid `ingredient_changes` in `recipe_change` model like this:

```
class RecipeChange < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredient_changes, reject_if: :invalid_ingredient_change?

  def invalid_ingredient_change?(attributes)
  end
end
```

See:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: B-E-A-Utiful....thank you that was exactly what I was looking for....so hard to search for the right things when you arent sure where to even begin